# Reading last five lines of a csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv

I'm using the following code to read the first 1000 lines - only the first 6 columns - from csv and keep them in the array P2(,):

```
fName = "c:\temp\filexx.csv"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
            Dim tmpstream As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fName)
            TextLine = tmpstream.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine(0), ",")
            For X = 0 To 999  'reading only the first 1000 lines
                strline = TextLine(X).Split(",")
                For Y = 0 To 5 '6 columns
                    P2(X, Y) = strline(Y)
                Next
            Next
            tmpstream.Close() 
        Else
            MsgBox("file doesn't exist")
        End If
```

But I'm interested in the last 5 lines. So, I'm supposed to change the

```
TextLine = tmpstream.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)
```

to sth similar to

```
TextLine = tmpstream.ReadLine(fName.Length - 6)
```

but I have no idea how to do it.
Thank you very much for your hints, your links, your patience and your clearness

Comment: what programming language is that?

Comment: @JimiDini Some kind of visual basic.

Comment: VB.Net most likely (System.IO namespace used)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to read the last 6 lines of a CSV is to read all lines, and keep track of the last 6 that you read.

Since the CSV format allows for each line to be of variable width, there is no way to compute the correct file offset to just load the last 6 lines.

You are currently reading in the entire file, creating an array `TextLine` containing all lines

```
TextLine = tmpstream.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)
```

Simply access the last 6 elements of `TextLine` to get your answer.

Comment: Can I go to the last lines this way?Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Length

Comment: Yes.  Use TextLine.Length to know how many lines there are in total, and output the last 6.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the fllwing:

```
 If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
            Dim tmpstream As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fName)
            Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(fName).Length 
            TextLine = tmpstream.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine(0), ",")
            For X = 0 To 4
                strline = TextLine(lineCount - X - 1).Split(",") 'trying to read the last 5 lines
                For Y = 0 To 5 '6 columns
                    P1(X, Y) = strline(Y)
                Next
            Next
            tmpstream.Close() 'close reader
        Else
            MsgBox("File doesn't exist")
        End If
```

But there is no way to read the last line. If I use `strline=TextLine(lineCount - X)` it breaks at P1(X, Y) = strline(Y) with X=0 and Y=1 I suppose because of trying to read strlline=TextLine(lineCount).
Thank you for your help.
I'm not sure of having broken the rules of the forum but I haven't found another way for writing the code.